# Multilingual text paragraph in one tag with big line height but different offset

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, dom

I did not know the correct technical terms in front end to describe, here is my expectation:
[image]

with html source:

```html
<lingual>
  <p>This is some English text. It is a long sentence that spans multiple lines. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. This is another English sentence that is also quite long.</p>
  <p>이것은 일부 영어 텍스트입니다. 여러 줄에 걸쳐 긴 문장입니다. 빠른 갈색 여우가 게으른 개를 뛰어넘습니다. 이것은 또 다른 영어 문장이며, 매우 길기도합니다.</p>
  <p>これはいくつかの英語のテキストです。複数行にまたがる長い文章です。素早い茶色の狐がのろまな犬を飛び越えます。これはまた、かなり長い英語の文です。</p>
</lingual>
```

Hope to develop a html tag or css style, containing multiple language paragraphs, could list each language after line-break. It is expected be convenient for human translator to contrast text translations. In many articles and books one paragraph could be very large, if list translation paragraphs one by one, people might easily loss text context and have trouble in tacking reading progress once switch a different language.

So the 'line-height' of this king of 'paragraph' would have to be `line-height*(line_height_of_English + line_height_of_Korean + line_height_of_Japanese)`, some css attribute such as 'font-size' may still be working for the paragraph, while some may not. If only one language paragraph exists, it appears the same as normal paragraph.

Is there any idea for implementing it or any existing great library? Seems a browser just have to render text with enough line space and different start position for each language text. Do I have to draw text in canvas? Seems dealing line-break and text layout would be great cumbersome, and its logic is actually same with a browser's.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, at least it could look like the effect I expect.
The main point is to make container behave like a stack(`Stack` in flutter, and `FrameLayout` in android), and let children offset a specific value:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.stack-layout {
  position: relative;

  border: solid 1px green;
}

.original {
  margin:0;
  line-height: 4em;
  position: relative;
  top: -1.5em;
}
.lingual {
  margin:0;
  line-height: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  text-decoration: overline red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Hope to develop a html tag or css style, containing multiple language paragraph.</p>

<div class="stack-layout">
  <p class="original">This is some English text. It is a long sentence that spans multiple lines. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. This is another English sentence that is also quite long.</p>
  <p class="lingual">이것은 일부 영어 텍스트입니다. 여러 줄에 걸쳐 긴 문장입니다. 빠른 갈색 여우가 게으른 개를 뛰어넘습니다. 이것은 또 다른 영어 문장이며, 매우 길기도합니다.</p>
  <p class="lingual" style="top:1.5em">これはいくつかの英語のテキストです。複数行にまたがる長い文章です。素早い茶色の狐がのろまな犬を飛び越えます。これはまた、かなり長い英語の文です。</p>
</div>

<p>Is there any idea for implementing it or any existing great library?</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The line-height value would be `line-height=<num of paragraphs>em + 0.5em*<num-1>`. With big line height, text's top position did not align with top of  wrapped line, we offset `-1.5em` and each child's top increase `1.5em`(1em of font-size + 0.5em of spacing).

bugs:

- Text selection: some lingual text could not be selected correctly.
- In some cases, e.g. original text has 2 wrapped line, but translation text has 3 lines, this would result in mass appearance.